# Bitrix mail php отправляется только от Администратора

Tags: битрикс, php

Всем доброго! такая проблема

```
if(!empty($_POST['obratPhone'])){
        $obratName = $_POST['obratName'];
        $obratPhone = $_POST['obratPhone'];
        $subject = "Заказ обратного звонка!";
        $headers = array(); 
        $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"; 
        $headers[] = "From: IDEALDOM <sender@domain.com>"; 
        $headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong < bcc@domain2.com > "; 
        $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>"; 
        $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}"; 
        $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    mail('insi-almaty@mail.ru', $subject, "Меня зовут :".$obratName." Перезвоните мне пожалуйста по данному номеру ".$obratPhone, implode("\r\n", $headers));
    header("location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."");
}
```

Функция отправляет письмо так как я сижу под администратором на сайте! простой пользователь отправить сообщение не может! с чем это связано?

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
IncludeTemplateLangFile(__FILE__);
//CUtil::InitJSCore();
//CJSCore::Init(array("jquery"));
function PR($o){
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    $bt = $bt[0];
    $dRoot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    $dRoot = str_replace("/","\\",$dRoot);
    $bt["file"] = str_replace($dRoot,"",$bt["file"]);
    $dRoot = str_replace("\\","/",$dRoot);
    $bt["file"] = str_replace($dRoot,"",$bt["file"]);
    ?>
    <div style="font-size:9pt;color:#000;background:#fff;border 1px dashed #000"></div>
    <div style="padding:3px 5px;background:#99CCFF;font-weight:bold;"><?=$bt["file"]?>[<?=$bt["line"]?>]</div>
    <pre style="padding:10px"><?print_r($o)?></pre>

    <?
} 
$curPage = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?=LANGUAGE_ID?>" lang="<?=LANGUAGE_ID?>">
<head>
    <?
    $APPLICATION->ShowHead();
    ?>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/obrat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery-func.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/css/obrat.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">if (document.documentElement) { document.documentElement.id = "js" }</script>
</head>
<body id="page_way">    
<div id="panel"><?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?></div>
<div class="pole">
    <div class="heading">
        <img title="Телефон компании Идеальный Dom" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/phone.png" alt="" />
        <h2>+7(727)390 26 60</h2>
        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "horizontal_idealdom_top", Array(
    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "bottom",   // Тип меню для первого уровня
    "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A",   // Тип кеширования
    "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",    // Время кеширования (сек.)
    "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
    "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "",    // Значимые переменные запроса
    "MAX_LEVEL" => "1", // Уровень вложенности меню
    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",    // Тип меню для остальных уровней
    "USE_EXT" => "N",   // Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php
    "DELAY" => "N", // Откладывать выполнение шаблона меню
    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",    // Разрешить несколько активных пунктов одновременно
    ),
    false
);?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
<div class="head">
<img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/Insi-most.jpg" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1"/>
</div>
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:menu",
    "bottom1",
    Array(
        "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
        "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
        "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "",
        "MAX_LEVEL" => "1",
        "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",
        "USE_EXT" => "N",
        "DELAY" => "N",
        "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N"
    )
);?>
<?
if(!empty($_POST['obratPhone'])){
        $obratName = $_POST['obratName'];
        $obratPhone = $_POST['obratPhone'];
        $subject = "Заказ обратного звонка!";
        $headers = array(); 
        $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"; 
        $headers[] = "From: IDEALDOM <sender@domain.com>"; 
        $headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong < bcc@domain2.com > "; 
        $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>"; 
        $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}"; 
        $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    mail('insi-almaty@mail.ru', $subject, "Меня зовут :".$obratName." Перезвоните мне пожалуйста по данному номеру ".$obratPhone, implode("\r\n", $headers));
    header("location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."");
}
?>
```

Comment: Как связан администратор CMS и функция PHP `mail` ? __(Подсказка: никак)__    
Ищите кусок кода, который либо прекращает работу кода до выполнения блока кода с отправкой письма, либо стоит условие, которое позволяет это только администратору.

Comment: прикрепил весь код страницы))) выше

Comment: руки таким битриксовцам поотрывал бы. 

Зачем вы пользуетесь mail и каким образом она отностится к битрикс???

И вообще какого оно в шаблоне сайта прописано!? Поставьте из маркетплейс обратный звонок и то лучше будет!!!

Comment: @binliz прав.  а еще проще будет подключить любой скрипт обратного звонка. делается это вставкой пару строчек в index-шаблон. есть полностью бесплатные решения.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущих комментаторов.

И вопрос -- код какой именно страницы вы прикрепили?
Ваша проблема, скорее всего, в том, что шаблон для простого пользователя кэшируется.

Comment: Поддержу предыдущих комментаторов, Вам бы сперва курсы по Битриксу почитать и документацию, хотя бы про встроенный механизм создания форм к которому уже прикручена отправка писем как админу о заполнении, так и заполнявшему. Какие права на страницу? И где собственно сама форма из которой берутся данные? Какие права на страницу с формой и саму форму?

Answer (score 2):

Так делать не надо! Если уж не пользуешься [веб-формами](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=41&CHAPTER_ID=742), то используй хотя бы [почтовые шаблоны](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=41&LESSON_ID=3523).
Создаешь почтовый шаблон и отправляешь его при помощи [CEvent::SendImmediate](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/sendimmediate.php) в своем скрипте. Разумеется, перед этим надо подключить API битрикса.